# How to return HTTP 500 from ASP.NET 5 Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core

The controller now has function `CreatedAtRoute()` for 201, `HttpBadRequest()` for 400, etc. I don't see one for 500 which I figure would be `HttpInternalServerError()`.

There is, however the `HttpStatusCodeResult` class which I can create and return:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]string something)
{    
   ...
    try{
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

But I want to return some info from `e`. This might be bad practice for live, but when we're testing, we'd like to see the errors from the returned body of the API call.

`HttpStatusCodeResult` does not have an property of type `object` or anything for the purpose of providing metadata.

What to do? I don't want to return a 400 because that's not what an Internal Server Error means.

Comment: I can't say for asp.net, but in many frameworks for Java there is often some type of `HTTPResponse` object that encapsulates both a response code and a response body. Might be something worth looking into.

Comment: Use the `HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode, String)` overload to provide a description. As far as passing an `object`, you're right--you can't. But that's per the protocol.

Comment: @CollinD - there doesn't seem to be a constructor with that second string parameter. I might be missing a reference to an extension.

Answer (score 5):

```
return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Message describing the error here"));
```

or

```
return InternalServerError(new Exception("SOME CUSTOM MESSAGE"));
```

Comment: I would to the later, since it's a Web Api 2.x approach.